# I don't understand why I see that the width of the entry(I gave: 146 pixels) is bigger then windows width(I gave 420 pixels )?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I encountered something I don't understand.
I could assume it is a different measurement but I can't find any information about it.

I don't understand why I see that the width of the entry(I gave: 146 pixels) is bigger then windows width(I gave 420 pixels ) ?
Increase the width of the window with the cursor and you will see that it is much wider than the window itself. Can you explain it ? How can this be controlled?

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

win.geometry("465x420")


entry1 = Entry(win, background="white", width=146)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `width` option for an `Entry` widget is by characters, not pixels.

Comment: Can you give me a formula how can I control width of an Entry by Windows width ?@acw1668

Comment: What do you mean by *"width of an Entry by Windows width"*?

Comment: For example, entry_width = windows_width/2 @acw1668

Comment: I think you mean "window width". "Window" is the thing you display, "Windows" is an operating system.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Paint a white rectangle?

Comment: You are correct @Finomnis

Comment: I need to use grid instead of pack. So, I need to control the width entry@acw1668

Comment: If you just want a white rectangle, use `Label` with an blank image, then the `width` option will be in pixels.

Comment: @Alex This doesn't paint a white rectangle tough, it creates a text field that you can click into and enter text. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Yes. It's for text @Finomnis

Comment: @Alex Might be relevant: https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pack-place-and-grid-in-tkinter/

Comment: You need to state clear in the question what you want on the width of the Entry widget. For example fixed width or relative to the parent, have to use `grid()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with the default font of Tkinter I divide the `window` size by `8` and round it.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

win.geometry("465x420")



entry1 = Entry(win, background="white")
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=0)


win.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: entry1.configure(width=round(e.width/8)))

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Finomnis Sorry for that I have updated that.

Comment: Why divided by 8 ? @codester_09

Comment: @Alex I google and found [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-many-pixel-width-for-one-char-in-tft-screen/464907) where they say _`"The space occupied by a character using the standard font is 6 pixels wide by 8 pixels high.
"`_ Then I try to dived the windows pixel by the one character pixel to get the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter has `w.winfo_width` to find the width of a widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

entry10 = tk.Entry( root, width = 10 )
entry20 = tk.Entry( root, width = 20 )

entry10.grid()
entry20.grid()

ttkentry10 = ttk.Entry( root, width = 10 )
ttkentry20 = ttk.Entry( root, width = 20 )

ttkentry10.grid()
ttkentry20.grid()


def on_click():
    print( '10: ', entry10.winfo_width(), '20: ', entry20.winfo_width() )
    print( 'ttk 10: ', ttkentry10.winfo_width(), 
           'ttk 20: ', ttkentry20.winfo_width() )

ttk.Button( root, text = 'Click', command = on_click ).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Results from click:

```
    10:  102     20:  192
ttk 10:  104  ttk20:  194
```

On my Mac this gives 9 pixels per character + 12 pixels for a `tk.Entry` and 9 pixels per character + 14 pixels for a `ttk.Entry` with the default font.